# How to create unit test for angulajs filter with dependency?

Tags: angularjs, filter

How ot create unit tests for me Angularjs filter called ?  Current code gives me error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.0/$injector/unpr?p0=DateForFrontEndFilterFilterProvider%20%3C-%20DateForFrontEndFilterFilter
>               at public/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:6:425
>               at public/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:44:395

My code is following:

Filter code:

```
app.filter('DateForFrontEndFilter', ['$filter', 'ngOtherSettings', function($filter, ngOtherSettings) {
    return function(date) {
        var format = ngOtherSettings.FrontEndDateFormat;
        var result = $filter('date')(date, format, null);
```

Test code:

```
describe('DateForFrontEndFilter tests', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {

        module.apply('myApp');

        inject(function($injector) {
            filter = $injector.get('$filter')('DateForFrontEndFilter');
        });

        var testDate = "10/12/2017 10:32:12";
    });


    it('check date from DateForFrontEndFilter for date with format long', function() {

        var ngOtherSettings = { FrontEndDateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' };
        var result = filter(ngOtherSettings, testDate);
        expect(result).toBe(testDate + "sda");
    });
            return result;
        };
    }]);
...
```

Comment: Use non-minified version of Angular to get better error messages. That error indicates that `DateForFrontEndFilter` cannot be found. Is it located in a different module than the one you are testing? Are all files loaded?

Comment: Thanks using not minified version helps:) good tip :)